# OpenCL traversal kernel - further optimization

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, traversal, raytracing

Currently, I have an OpenCL kernel for like traversal as below. I'd be glad if someone had some point on optimization of this quite large kernel.

The thing is, I'm running this code with SAH BVH and I'd like to get performance similar to Timo Aila with his traversals in his paper (Understanding the Efficiency of Ray Traversal on GPUs), of course his code uses SplitBVH (which I might consider using in place of SAH BVH, but in my opinion it has really slow build times). But I'm asking about traversal, not BVH (also I've so far worked only with scenes, where SplitBVH won't give you much advantages over SAH BVH).

First of all, here is what I have so far (standard while-while traversal kernel).

```
__constant sampler_t sampler = CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

// Inline definition of horizontal max
inline float max4(float a, float b, float c, float d)
{
    return max(max(max(a, b), c), d);
}

// Inline definition of horizontal min
inline float min4(float a, float b, float c, float d)
{
    return min(min(min(a, b), c), d);
}

// Traversal kernel
__kernel void traverse( __read_only image2d_t nodes,
                        __global const float4* triangles,
                        __global const float4* rays,
                        __global float4* result,
                        const int num,
                        const int w,
                        const int h)
{
    // Ray index
    int idx = get_global_id(0);

    if(idx < num)
    {
        // Stack
        int todo[32];
        int todoOffset = 0;

        // Current node
        int nodeNum = 0;

        float tmin = 0.0f;
        float depth = 2e30f;

        // Fetch ray origin, direction and compute invdirection
        float4 origin = rays[2 * idx + 0];
        float4 direction = rays[2 * idx + 1];
        float4 invdir = native_recip(direction);

        float4 temp = (float4)(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Traversal loop
        while(true)
        {
            // Fetch node information
            int2 nodeCoord = (int2)((nodeNum << 2) % w, (nodeNum << 2) / w);
            int4 specs = read_imagei(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord + (int2)(3, 0));

            // While node isn't leaf
            while(specs.z == 0)
            {
                // Fetch child bounding boxes
                float4 n0xy = read_imagef(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord);
                float4 n1xy = read_imagef(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord + (int2)(1, 0));
                float4 nz = read_imagef(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord + (int2)(2, 0));

                // Test ray against child bounding boxes
                float oodx = origin.x * invdir.x;
                float oody = origin.y * invdir.y;
                float oodz = origin.z * invdir.z;
                float c0lox = n0xy.x * invdir.x - oodx;
                float c0hix = n0xy.y * invdir.x - oodx;
                float c0loy = n0xy.z * invdir.y - oody;
                float c0hiy = n0xy.w * invdir.y - oody;
                float c0loz = nz.x * invdir.z - oodz;
                float c0hiz = nz.y * invdir.z - oodz;
                float c1loz = nz.z * invdir.z - oodz;
                float c1hiz = nz.w * invdir.z - oodz;
                float c0min = max4(min(c0lox, c0hix), min(c0loy, c0hiy), min(c0loz, c0hiz), tmin);
                float c0max = min4(max(c0lox, c0hix), max(c0loy, c0hiy), max(c0loz, c0hiz), depth);
                float c1lox = n1xy.x * invdir.x - oodx;
                float c1hix = n1xy.y * invdir.x - oodx;
                float c1loy = n1xy.z * invdir.y - oody;
                float c1hiy = n1xy.w * invdir.y - oody;
                float c1min = max4(min(c1lox, c1hix), min(c1loy, c1hiy), min(c1loz, c1hiz), tmin);
                float c1max = min4(max(c1lox, c1hix), max(c1loy, c1hiy), max(c1loz, c1hiz), depth);

                bool traverseChild0 = (c0max >= c0min);
                bool traverseChild1 = (c1max >= c1min);

                nodeNum = specs.x;
                int nodeAbove = specs.y;

                // We hit just one out of 2 childs
                if(traverseChild0 != traverseChild1)
                {
                    if(traverseChild1)
                    {
                        nodeNum = nodeAbove;
                    }
                }
                // We hit either both or none
                else
                {
                    // If we hit none, pop node from stack (or exit traversal, if stack is empty)
                    if (!traverseChild0)
                    {
                        if(todoOffset == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        nodeNum = todo[--todoOffset];
                    }
                    // If we hit both
                    else
                    {
                        // Sort them (so nearest goes 1st, further 2nd)
                        if(c1min < c0min)
                        {
                            unsigned int tmp = nodeNum;
                            nodeNum = nodeAbove;
                            nodeAbove = tmp;
                        }

                        // Push further on stack
                        todo[todoOffset++] = nodeAbove;
                    }
                }

                // Fetch next node information
                nodeCoord = (int2)((nodeNum << 2) % w, (nodeNum << 2) / w);
                specs = read_imagei(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord + (int2)(3, 0));
            }

            // If node is leaf & has some primitives
            if(specs.z > 0)
            {
                // Loop through primitives & perform intersection with them (Woop triangles)
                for(int i = specs.x; i < specs.y; i++)
                {
                    // Fetch first point from global memory
                    float4 v0 = triangles[i * 4 + 0];

                    float o_z = v0.w - origin.x * v0.x - origin.y * v0.y - origin.z * v0.z;
                    float i_z = 1.0f / (direction.x * v0.x + direction.y * v0.y + direction.z * v0.z);
                    float t = o_z * i_z;

                    if(t > 0.0f && t < depth)
                    {
                        // Fetch second point from global memory
                        float4 v1 = triangles[i * 4 + 1];

                        float o_x = v1.w + origin.x * v1.x + origin.y * v1.y + origin.z * v1.z;
                        float d_x = direction.x * v1.x + direction.y * v1.y + direction.z * v1.z;
                        float u = o_x + t * d_x;

                        if(u >= 0.0f && u <= 1.0f)
                        {
                            // Fetch third point from global memory
                            float4 v2 = triangles[i * 4 + 2];

                            float o_y = v2.w + origin.x * v2.x + origin.y * v2.y + origin.z * v2.z;
                            float d_y = direction.x * v2.x + direction.y * v2.y + direction.z * v2.z;
                            float v = o_y + t * d_y;

                            if(v >= 0.0f && u + v <= 1.0f)
                            {
                                // We got successful hit, store the information
                                depth = t;
                                temp.x = u;
                                temp.y = v;
                                temp.z = t;
                                temp.w = as_float(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Pop node from stack (if empty, finish traversal)
            if(todoOffset == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            nodeNum = todo[--todoOffset];
        }

        // Store the ray traversal result in global memory
        result[idx] = temp;
    }
}
```

First question of the day is, how could one write his Persistent while-while and Speculative while-while kernel in OpenCL?

**Ad Persistent while-while**, do I get it right, that I actually just start kernel with global work size equivalent to local work size, and both these numbers should be equal to warp/wavefront size of the GPU?
I get that with CUDA the persistent thread implementation looks like this:

```
  do
  {
        volatile int& jobIndexBase = nextJobArray[threadIndex.y];

        if(threadIndex.x == 0)
        {
              jobIndexBase = atomicAdd(&warpCounter, WARP_SIZE);
        }

        index = jobIndexBase + threadIndex.x;

        if(index >= totalJobs)
              return;

        /* Perform work for task numbered 'index' */
  }
  while(true);
```

How could equivalent in OpenCL look like, I know I'll have to do some barriers in there, I also know that one should be after the score where I atomically add WARP_SIZE to warpCounter.

**Ad Speculative traversal** - well I probably don't have any ideas how this should be implemented in OpenCL, so any hints are welcome. I also don't have idea where to put barriers (because putting them around simulated __any will result in driver crash).

If you made it here, thanks for reading & any hints, answers, etc. are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

An optimization you can do is use vector variables and the fused multiply add function to speed up your set up math. As for the rest of the kernel, It is slow because it is branchy. If you can make assumptions on the signal data you might be able to reduce the execution time by reducing the code branches. I have not checked the float4 swizles (the .xxyy and .x .y .z .w after the float 4 variables) so just check that.

```
            float4 n0xy = read_imagef(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord);
            float4 n1xy = read_imagef(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord + (int2)(1, 0));
            float4 nz = read_imagef(nodes, sampler, nodeCoord + (int2)(2, 0));

            float4 oodf4 = -origin * invdir;

            float4 c0xyf4 = fma(n0xy,invdir.xxyy,oodf4);

            float4 c0zc1z = fma(nz,(float4)(invdir.z),oodf4);

            float c0min = max4(min(c0xyf4.x, c0xyf4.y), min(c0xyf4.z, c0xyf4.w), min(c0zc1z.z, c0zc1z.w), tmin);
            float c0max = min4(max(c0xyf4.x, c0xyf4.y), max(c0xyf4.z, c0xyf4.w), max(c0zc1z.z, c0zc1z.w), depth);

            float4 c1xy = fma(n1xy,invdir.xxyy,oodf4);

            float c1min = max4(min(c1xy.x, c1xy.y), min(c1xy.z, c1xy.w), min(c0zc1z.z, c0zc1z.w), tmin);
            float c1max = min4(max(c1xy.x, c1xy.y), max(c1xy.z, c1xy.w), max(c0zc1z.z, c0zc1z.w), depth);
```